# Angular Typeahead box is showing way above search field

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

The results for my typeahead search are showing way above the actual input field. The Company Name field is where my actual input is but the results are way north of that.

[image]

Here's my code. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<span ng-switch-when="typeahead">
          <input type="text"
                 class="form-control"
                 placeholder="Search..."
                 typeahead="option.value as option.displayValue for option in formField.options | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:3"
                 ng-model="formModel[formField.field.columnName]" />
    </span>
```

Controller:

```
(function(angular){
"use strict";

var module = angular.module('xdock.formField',[]);

module.constant('FORM_FIELD_TYPES', ["text", "number", "date", "lookup", "check", "timepicker", "typeahead"]);

module.directive('formField',[
    function formField() {
        return {
            scope: {
                formField: '=',
                formLabel: '@',
                formModel: '=',
                formErrorModel: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'common/formField.html',
            link: function postLink(scope) {
                scope.flags = {datepickerOpen : false};
                scope.datepickerOptions = {
                    showButtonBar: false
                };

                scope.openDatepicker = function openDatepicker($evt) {
                    $evt.preventDefault();
                    $evt.stopPropagation();
                    scope.flags.datepickerOpen = true;
                };

                function formatDate() {
                    if(scope.formField.type === "date" && scope.formModel[scope.formField.field.columnName]) {
                        scope.formModel[scope.formField.field.columnName] =
                            new Date(scope.formModel[scope.formField.field.columnName]);
                    }
                }

                formatDate();
            }
        };
    }

]);
```

}(window.angular));

Comment: please share your controller code

Comment: Added that. I don't have anything in there specific to the typeahead.

Comment: Did you add any Css for the company name field?

Comment: No I don't have any CSS for this particular field.

Comment: I tried creating codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jAZBxK  but couldn't replicate :(

Comment: Right, that's because you won't have the data that I'm getting in my typeahead element.